# counting the number of substrings in a string

Tags: python, string, loops, error-handling, while-loop

I am working on an Python assignment and I am stuck here.

Apparently, I have to write a code that counts the number of a given substring within a string.

I thought I got it right, then I am stuck here.

```
def count(substr,theStr):
    # your code here
    num = 0
    i = 0
    while substr in theStr[i:]:
        i = i + theStr.find(substr)+1
        num = num + 1

    return num

substr = 'is'
theStr = 'mississipi'
print(count(substr,theStr))
```

if I run this, I expect to get **2** as the result, rather, I get **3**...

See, other examples such as `ana` and `banana` works fine, but this specific example keeps making the error. I don't know what I did wrong here.

Would you PLEASE help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
while substr in theStr[i:]:
```

correctly advances over the target string `theStr`, however the

```
i = i + theStr.find(substr)+1
```

keeps looking from the start of `theStr`.

The [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method accepts optional *start* and *end* arguments to limit the search:

> `str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring *sub* is found
>   within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments *start* and *end*
>   are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if *sub* is not found.

We don't really need to use `in` here: we can just check that `find` doesn't return -1. It's a bit wasteful performing an `in` search when we then need to repeat the search using `find` to get the index of the substring.

I assume that you want to find overlapping matches, since the [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method can find non-overlapping matches, and since it's implemented in C it's more efficient than implementing it yourself in Python.

```
def count(substr, theStr):
    num = i = 0
    while True:
        j = theStr.find(substr, i)
        if j == -1:
            break
        num += 1
        i = j + 1
    return num

print(count('is', 'mississipi'))
print(count('ana', 'bananana'))
```

**output**

```
2
3
```

The core of this code is

```
j = theStr.find(substr, i)
```

`i` is initialised to 0, so we start searching from the beginning of `theStr`, and because of `i = j + 1` subsequent searches start looking from the index following the last found match.

Answer (score 0):

The code change you need is -

```
i = i + theStr[i:].find(substr)+ 1
```

instead of

```
i = i + theStr.find(substr)+ 1
```

In your code the substring is always found until `i` reaches position 4 or more. But while finding the index of the substring, you were using the original(whole) string which in turn returns the position as 1.

In your example of `banana`, after first iteration `i` becomes 2. So, in next iteration `str[i:]` becomes `nana`. And the position of substring `ana` in this sliced string and the original string is 1. So, the bug in the code is just suppressed and the code seems to work fine.

If your code is purely for learning purpose, the you can do this way. Otherwise you may want to make use of python provided functions (like `count()`) to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the number of substrings:

```
def count(substr,theStr):
    num = 0
    for i in range(len(theStr)):
        if theStr[i:i+len(substr)] == substr:
            num += 1
    return num

substr = 'is'
theStr = 'mississipi'
print(count(substr,theStr))
```

O/P : 2

where `theStr[i:i+len(substr)]` is slice string, i is strating index and `i+len(substr)` is ending index.

Eg.

> i = 0
>
> substr length  = 2
>
> first-time compare substring is => mi

[String slice more details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: The SO community will do this by using upvote or downvote. See [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).